# How can I make an iframe breakout when a form is submitted? I do not have access to the iframe page code

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe, breakout

I am trying to let users on my site enter their user name for an external site and then be redirected to that site to enter their password. I tried to go to the other site and view the form details and copy the hidden fields to let my form, but the site sets some of those hidden fields dynamically.

So I think the best solution next is to put the page into an iframe.  The page in the iframe only has a form to enter the User ID, then redirects for the password.

Is there a way that I can have the iframe breakout after the user submits the form in the iframe?

Preferably in html, php, or javascript.
-Bryan

Comment: it'd have to be html/javascript. PHP can't make anything "break out", since it's running on the server.

Comment: Take a look at [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)